# Is Revelation 10:5-7 restating that which is found in Daniel 12:7?

Tags: revelation, daniel

In the Book of Daniel we read a curious passage:

> **Daniel 12:7**: "I heard **the man dressed in linen, who was above the waters of the river, as he raised his right hand and his left toward heaven, and swore by Him who lives forever that it would be for a time, times, and half a time**; and as soon as they finish shattering the power of the holy people, all these events will be completed."

On the surface, it seems that this may be restated in the Book of Revelation:

> **Revelation 10:5-7**: "Then **the angel whom I saw standing on the sea and on the land lifted up his right hand to heaven, <sup>6</sup>and swore by Him who lives forever and ever**, WHO CREATED HEAVEN AND THE THINGS IN IT, AND THE EARTH AND THE THINGS IN IT, AND THE SEA AND THE THINGS IN IT, **that there will be delay no longer**, <sup>7</sup>but in the days of the voice of the seventh angel, when he is about to sound, then the mystery of God is finished, as He preached to His servants the prophets."

I was unable to find an answer to this. Are these sets of passages referring to the same event?

Answer (score 1):

All this says is that there is an allusion as follows.

> Rev 10:5-7 - Then the angel I had seen standing on the sea and on the
> land lifted up his right hand to heaven. And he swore by Him who lives
> forever and ever, who created heaven and everything in it, the earth
> and everything in it, and the sea and everything in it: “There will be
> no more delay! But in the days of the voice of the seventh angel, when
> he is about to sound his trumpet, the mystery of God will be
> fulfilled, just as He proclaimed to His servants the prophets.”

- Dan 12:7 - And the man dressed in linen, who was above the waters of the river, **raised his right hand and his left hand toward heaven, and I heard him swear by Him who lives forever**, saying, “It will be for a time, and times, and half a time. When the power of the holy people has finally been shattered, all these things will be completed.”
- Ex 20:11 - For in six days **the LORD made the heavens and the earth and the sea and all that is in them**, but on the seventh day He rested. Therefore the LORD blessed the Sabbath day and set it apart as holy.
- Eze 12:25 - because I, the LORD, will speak whatever word I speak, and it will be **fulfilled without delay**. For in your days, O rebellious house, I will speak a message and bring it to pass, declares the Lord GOD.’ ”

Later in the same chapter we find this in Rev 10:

> **8** Then the voice that I had heard from heaven spoke to me again, saying, “Go, take the small scroll that lies open in the hand of the
> angel standing on the sea and on the land.” **9** And I went to the
> angel and said, “Give me the small scroll.” “Take it and eat it,” he
> said. “It will make your stomach bitter, but in your mouth it will be
> as sweet as honey.” **10** So I took the small scroll from the angel’s
> hand and ate it; and it was as sweet as honey in my mouth, but when I
> had eaten it, my stomach turned bitter.

This clearly alludes to:

- Eze 2:9 - 3:3 -  Then I looked and saw a hand reaching out to me, and in it was a scroll, which He unrolled before me. And written on the front and back of it were words of lamentation, mourning, and woe. “Son of man,” He said to me, “eat what you find here. Eat this scroll, then go and speak to the house of Israel.” So I opened my mouth, and He fed me the scroll. “Son of man,” He said to me, “eat and fill your stomach with this scroll I am giving you.” So I ate, and it was as sweet as honey in my mouth.

A literary allusion or literary parallel does not necessarily mean they are discussing the same event (although this is not excluded).  It simply means that one is, at last, being used to import the meaning of the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Daniel and Revelation are obviously connected.

> And after 32 *captivities* [Daniel 9:2,3-19, 2 Chronicles 36:21,22] **shall Messiah suffer the death penalty,
> but not for Himself**. And the people of the prince [John 14:30] that
> shall come shall destroy the city and the sanctuary
> **and the end thereof shall be with a flood**

Daniel 9:26

> And she [Israel, David's line] brought forth a male child who was to
> rule all nations [the Messiah]... and her child was caught up to God,
> and to His throne. [Rev 5]
>
> And the serpent cast out of his mouth **a river of water as a flood
> after the woman** that he **might cause her to be carried away of the
> flood**.

Revelation 12:5,15

- Ezekiel and Revelation are also clearly telling the same prophecy:

1. Ezekiel 37:1-15 == Resurrections

> "Come **from the four winds** [Matt 24:31] Oh breath of life and breath upon these
> **slain** that they may live. **And they stood upon their feet an exceedingly great army** .. **I will open up your graves and bring you up
> out of your graves.** "

2. Ezekiel 37:15-28 == Reign

> "And David my servant shall be king among them, and they all shall
> have one shepherd"
> [ "David, whom I will raise up unto them" Jeremiah 30:9 literal resurrection ]

literal resurrection as proved and demonstrated fully by Christ,
and when Paul read passages such as Isaiah 26:19, and Ezekiel 37:1-15
we can be sure he thought it was speaking about actual resurrection
(Acts 23:6-8) and, it is about actual resurrection.

3. Ezekiel 38 and 39 == Gog and Magog.

> "And the word of the Lord came to me saying, Son of man, set thy face
> against Gog, the land of Magog"

1. Revelation 20:4-5 == Resurrections

> "this is the first resurrection"

2. Revelation 20:5-7 == Reign

> "And shall reign with Him 1000 years"

3. Revelation 20:7-10 == Gog and Magog.

> "..Gog and Magog, to gather them together for battle.. and fire came
> down from God out of heaven, and devoured them [Rev 20:9 == Ez 38:22,
> 39:6] "

- Isaiah and Revelation tell the same prophecy:

1. Isaiah 26:19 Resurrections

> "Israel's dead men shall rise, together with my dead body shall they
> arise"

2. Isaiah 27:1 Two beasts slain

> "In that day, the Lord with **His severe and strong sword** shall punish
> Leviathan the fleeing serpent, even Leviathan  that twisted serpent;
> and He shall slay the dragon that is in the sea."

1. Revelation 19:7-8, 14  Resurrections

> "Let us be glad and rejoice for the marriage of the Lamb has come, and
> His bride has made herself ready. And to her it was granted that she
> should be arrayed in fine linen"
>
> And the armies in the sky followed Him on white horses, clothed in
> fine linen"

Together with Ezekiel 37:9-10, Jude 1:14-15, Psalm 58:10 and Malachi 4:2-3
we know that the army spoken of in Revelation 19:14 is an army of resurrected saints,
the same exceedingly great army, from the four winds, prophesied in Ezekiel.

Therefore we can conclude that the marriage supper of the Lamb is the first resurrection.

We are literally caught up in the air together with people such as David and Isaiah,
to meet the Lord in the air, as part of the exceedingly great army.
We get to watch the Lord, with His sword, slay Leviathan and the Dragon.

> For the righteous shall rejoice when they see the vengeance, he shall
> wash his feet in the blood of the wicked
>
> Unto you who fear my name shall the Son of righteousness arise... the
> wicked **shall be ashes under your feet** **in the day that I do this says
> the Lord.**

Psalm 58:10, Malachi 4:2-3

> In flaming fire taking vengeance on them that know not God.. When the
> Lord shall come to be glorified in His saints

Second Thessalonians 1:7-10 is clearly the day Paul also is talking about.

2. Revelation 19:20-21  Two beasts slain

> And the beast was taken, and with him the false prophet... [Leviathan and the dragon] these **both**
> were cast alive into a lake burning with fire and brimstone And the
> rest were slain with the **sword** of Him that sat upon the horse which
> **sword** **proceeded** **from His mouth** **and all the birds were filled with
> their flesh**.

> **For wheresoever the bodies are there will the birds be gathered
> together**.

Matthew 24:28, Luke 17:37

All of the prophecies are very clearly connected if we just let scripture alone
do the interpretation and do not overlook the connections that it gives us.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).